# Mounting a tri-clamp Tee fitting

Tags: tubing

Is there any specific hardware for mounting piping and/or tri-clamp to a wall?

I'm looking to have a tri-clamp tee in a fixed location on my wall - looking for hardware to secure it. Hoping to find something other than a couple worm clamps.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what size piping or tri-clamp you're working with, you could probably go with [1/2" pipe mounts](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Arctic-Cove-1-2-in-Hanging-Mount-5-Pack-MAC400HM/204767991) or many of the options [I found here](https://www.google.com/search?q=stainless%20steel%20pipe%20hanger&oq=stainless%20steel%20pipe%20hanger&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2.5150j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=stainless%20steel%20pipe%20hanger&safe=off&tbm=shop&*). There's a lot of options for securing pipes to your wall — what would probably help you most is to figure out what your requirements are for securing the pipe and/or TC.  Size, mobility, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The company that I work for offers a couple of different options for securing pipe/tubing to walls and ceilings.  You can check out our [tube hanger options here](https://sanitaryfittings.us/product-category/fittings/hangers).  Both of the options we offer can be customized to include a 3/8" coupler on top.  This would allow you to secure a wall/ceiling flange to your mounting point.  From there you would thread a 3/8" rod into your tube/pipe hangers which would hold up your equipment.

Wall mounted support systems are not as secure as ceiling mount depending upon the distance these items are placed from the wall.

Please let us know if you have any questions on this.

John
Sanitary Fittings, LLC